# How can I identify Eridian/E-tech style weapons

Tags: borderlands-2

I've found a few E-Tech weapons but my buddies and I weren't 100% sure how to identify them at a glance. The things I've noticed is that all the E-tech guns I've seen use more than one bullet, have multiple special effects listed, and have a specific reddish purple color.

I'm thinking the color is the key but I've gotten other purple guns; not the same *shade* of purple though. I wasn't sure if the shades indicate rarity (like shades of orange in Borderlands 1) or if that shade of reddish purple is specific to E-tech.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From some [Forum threads](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=149287) it sounds like the magenta/purple/pink hue really is how you identify an E-tech gun.

> Another difference from Borderlands 1 is that Eridian weapons now have their own specific rarity color, dark-pink.

I've confirmed this with 6 guns so far, though I'm unsure if there are different "levels" of magenta rarities for E-tech guns like there were shades of orange for Borderlands 1.

Comment: Dark pink sounds awfully close to purple; this'll cause some problems.

Comment: @fbueckert it's magenta, I just included the other colors for those who search. It's one of those colors everyone interprets differently, especially with different monitors. "Dark pink" is an oxymoron since it's not pink, it's lightish-red.

Comment: Confusing weapon tier colors is also a franchise staple!

Comment: Yeah, BL1 had "pearl" colored weapons, didn't it?  I suppose confusing and similar colors really are part of their franchise.

Comment: @fbueckert "pearl" guns were initially a bug; legendary guns that turned out white instead of orange; that got fixed. Armory of Knoxx added Pearlescent (cyan) guns, which were better than orange (despite blue being worse than orange).

Answer (score 6):

E-Tech guns have a magenta color, as you said, a slightly pinker shade of purple. They also have unique names (all e-tech SMG's are called Plasma Caster, for example, regardless of manufacturer). You can see all the names here: http://www.bl2wiki.com/E-Tech

Most notably, all e-tech guns fire energy projectiles instead of normal bullets (or instead of rockets in the case of e-tech rocket launchers). If your weapon is firing glowing darts or orbs of energy, it's e-tech.

Answer (score 1):

Also, they all have fins that glows on the side towards the user and open out every time a round is fired. From pistols to rockets, they all have fins that glow.